# Override autowired instance with a mock

Tags: java, testing, mocking, mockito, spy

ServiceInstance.createInstance is supposed to be called when a PUT call is made to the URL below. To be able to test if the correct method is called when a PUT request is sent, I want to mock the object(ServiceInstance) that has the method called. However, the mock doesn't override the real instance. What am I missing in this setting?

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = { MySpringBootApplication.class })
@SpyBean(ServiceInstance.class)

public class ServiceTest {

@Autowired
ServiceInstance serviceInstance;

@BeforeClass
public static void setUp() {
    SpringApplication.run(MySpringBootApplication.class, new String[] {});
}

@Test
public void sendPutRequest() throws JSONException, ClientProtocolException, IOException {
    CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
    HttpPut putRequest = new HttpPut("http://localhost:8080/v2/instances/1");
    //.....

    httpClient.execute(putRequest);
    Mockito.verify(serviceInstance, Mockito.times(1)).createInstance(Mockito.any());

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a profile for test

```
@Profile("test")
@Configuration
public class ServiceInstanceConfiguration {
   @Bean
   @Primary
   public ServiceInstance serviceInstance() {
    return Mockito.mock(ServiceInstance.class);
   }
}
```

and run your test with profile "test"

```
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = { MySpringBootApplication.class })
public class ServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    ServiceInstance serviceInstance;
  //...
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are not using mock, but you used spy, so real object and real method was called.

Instead of SpyBean annotation try to use MockBean annotation (it mocks bean in Spring context)

[Example](https://gooroo.io/GoorooTHINK/Article/16943/Spring-Boot-14--MockBean-and-SpyBean/24301#.W6tPB_YwhPY)